# Seal on forehead according to Revelation 9:4

Tags: revelation, new-testament

What kind of seal or mark and what  would it look like?  Revelation 9:4 talks about a seal on the forehead.

**Revelation 9:4**

> "They were told not to harm the grass of the earth or any green plant or any tree, but only those people who do not have the seal of God on their foreheads". ESV.

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your question. If you do not like what I have done please remove what I have done.

Comment: Possibly we were thinking about the wrong type of seal, and this guy has the right idea. (Comment rather than answer, due to non-seriousness.) https://youtu.be/SUYXsZA9K5E

Comment: I think the simple explanation of why only people without God’s mark were affected by that torment was that the people with God’s mark had already been taken out of the way. The mark doesn’t have to be a physical mark, it could simply mean “mark of approval”, but if it was a physical mark it could maybe have been a mystical Christian sign, of which there are a few of.

Answer (score 9):

We need to compare what Deuteronomy says about keeping the Lords words of commandment (Deuteronomy ch11 vv18-22).

They are to be kept in the heart and the soul and talked about constantly. They are to be bound "as a sign upon your hand and they shall be frontlets between your eyes" and also on the doorposts and the gates. It is well-known that the Pharisees were very careful to observe the commands about keeping the law in physical locations. In my mind, this is an excellent illustration of the way that over-literalism can miss the point. Surely the intent of that passage is that they are to keep God's law in the forefront of their *minds and hearts*. As long as they are doing that, the rest can be taken as metaphorical.

We ought to notice that the two locations identified in Revelation ch13 v16 match part of the command in Deuteronomy ch11 v18. In other words, they should be taken as the hostile equivalent of the command in Deuteronomy. Deuteronomy wants people to be focussed on God's law. The beast's order in v16 indicates in symbolism that the followers of the beast are to be focussed on the beast's law. Or rather his lawlessness- his ANOMIA (see 1 Thessalonians ch2 v3 and 1 John ch3 v4).

If the mention of "right hand" and "forehead" has that symbolic purpose, it may not be necessary to take the locations as literal.

And I suggest that the same is true about God's mark in ch 9v4. It points us back to the command in Deuteronomy. It is an indicator that these people, at least, have not abandoned God's law in favour of the beast. I believe the seal in Revelation to be the same seal offered in Ephesians; "You were sealed with the promised Holy Spirit"- Ephesians ch1 v13.

This works because the attack of the locusts is a spiritual attack (the victims are afflicted with despair, which is the opposite of faith), and therefore it needs to be met with a spiritual defence.

Comment: Thank you for enlightened me

Answer (score 4):

A seal was mentioned earlier in Revelation 7:3 and needs to be considered in conjunction with the seal mentioned in 9:4.

> "Hurt not the earth, neither the sea, nor the trees, till we have
> sealed the servants of our God in their foreheads." Revelation 7:3-4 K.J.V.

The text in question conversely speaks of those people who do ***not*** have the seal of God on their foreheads. The Revelation goes on to say that all those who do not have the seal of God on their foreheads end up with the mark of the beast on either their foreheads, or their right hands:

> "And he causeth all, both small and great, rich and poor, free and
> bond, to receive a mark in their right hand, or in their foreheads:
> ...count the number of the beast: for it is the number of a man; and
> his number is Six hundred threescore and six." Revelation 13:16-18
> K.J.V.

Comparing the two different 'marks' shows that one group has a mark on their forehead that is the seal of God which enables his angels to protect them through the plagues prior to Christ's return. Everyone else in the world has the mark of the beast on either their forehead, or their right hand. This identifies them as those who must have plagues from heaven poured out upon them, in judgment.

Given that this last book in the Bible is apocalyptic literature, using visions and symbolic languages and numbers throughout, the mark in question is no more literal than any of the other signs, wonders, and visions. Here is an explanation of those sealed with the seal of the living God, in their foreheads, whereby we can then compare the other seal in Rev. 9:4:

> "After this [Rev. 7:3], the winds might blow. But not on those who had
> been sealed, so as to hurt *them*. They were sealed, so that they were
> *safe before the event* ...Symbolically, the stamp or seal authenticates the elect *in the sight of the avenging angels*.
>
> The seal is that of the living God: Father, Son, and Holy Ghost. It is
> the power of divine *life* - eternal life - which brings home this
> seal. Everlasting life, in present communion, the life of the Father,
> and the Son by the Holy Ghost, distinguishes those sealed by the
> *living* God. God has brought home his work with unquestionable, divine authenticity, and this can be seen in the *spiritual life* of
> his servants.
>
> But in the forehead. This fronts the mind, or mentality. Here is a
> people transformed by the renewing of their minds. God has applied the
> doctrine of Christ. Their spiritual minds have received the love of
> the truth. Their mentality, quickened by the living God, is full of
> *the gospel of God*. The evangel, the apostles' doctrine, has been conveyed and stamped within by the revelation of the Holy Ghost - the
> Spirit of truth - the seal of which the angel ascending from the east
> confirms in the sight of the angels of judgment." *The Revelation of
> Jesus Christ*, pp 200-201, John Metcalfe

***This prepares us to now understand the drastic differences between those with the mark of God in their foreheads, and the people with the mark of the beast in their foreheads*** (or right hands). The verse in question shows that people can either have God's seal, or the number of the beast. The latter are tormented (when the fifth symbolic trumpet sounds). The latter are then doomed to awful, eternal judgment, because they are clearly identified as worshippers of the satanic beastly system that deceives the whole world, prior to Christ's return. Their minds have been controlled by those satanic forces. Their right hands are doing the work of the symbolic beast. They are at enmity against God and Christ.

The forehead, in Revelation, speaks of the mind - what one thinks and believes, which causes one to act accordingly. God identifies those who belong to him by faith, and they are set apart. The rest have the mark of the beast, which controls their thinking, and thus their actions. This is all in order for the avenging angels to either protect or torment. **There is nothing visible to be literally seen on anybody's forehead.** No human will see anything. **But the angels know what the spiritual mark looks like, and what the beastly mark looks like. Those marks are spiritually discerned.**

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the general assessment of @Stephen Disraeli here, although I do not think we need to go back to Deuteronomy to understand the issue. Rather, we simply need to understand that apocalyptic literature is highly symbolic and few details in the Book of Revelation are meant to be taken literally. As the Catholic editors of the [New American Bible](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/revelation/0) put it:

> Symbolic descriptions are not to be taken as literal descriptions, nor
> is the symbolism meant to be pictured realistically. One would find it
> difficult and repulsive to visualize a lamb with seven horns and seven
> eyes; yet Jesus Christ is described in precisely such words (Rev 5:6).

In this light, we are not dealing with a literal seal here, but with a symbol of God's invisible protection. The reference to Eph. 1:13 is apt. So is 2 Cor. 1:21-22:

> Now it is God who makes both us and you stand firm in Christ. He
> anointed us, set his seal of ownership on us, and put his Spirit in
> our hearts as a deposit, guaranteeing what is to come.

What Paul is speaking of here is simply a positive affirmation of Christian faith. **Presuming a unity of mind between Paul and John of Patmos here, we need not think of the seal mentioned in Revelation 9 as an external sign. Rather it represents God's protective blessing based on an internal commitment to persevere in faith through tribulation.**

Answer (score 1):

The most consistent way to understand the book of Revelation is to seek the precedents for the symbols elsewhere in the Bible.

Only the New Testament discusses the Seal of God.  Literal seals were made of wax and impressed with a unique image to certify ownership, authority or origin.  They were used on letters and legal documents and also on objects such as the tomb of Jesus (Matt 27:66) to prevent unauthorized interference or tampering with the contents.

When applied to people, the same concept applied – the seal of God was used to certify ownership (2 Tim 2:19).  Paul suggests that circumcision used to act as God’s seal (Rom 4:11).  Seal or sealing is used to describe the gift of the Holy Spirit

- 2 Cor 1:22 - the One also having sealed us and having given the **pledge of the Spirit in our hearts**.
- Eph 1:13, 14 - And in Him, having heard and believed the word of truth—the gospel of your salvation—you were **sealed with the promised Holy Spirit**, who is the pledge of our inheritance until the redemption of those who are God’s possession, to the praise of His glory.
- Eph 4:30 - And do not grieve the Holy Spirit of God, **in whom you were sealed** for the day of redemption.
- John 6:27 - Do not work for the food that is perishing, but for the food enduring unto **eternal life**, which the Son of Man will give to you; for God the Father has **sealed Him**."

Thus, the gift of the Holy Spirit is given to the redeemed when we seek the bread of life that endures to eternal life (John 6:27).  By this gift we, in turn, also certify that God is true

- John 3:33 - The one having received His testimony has set **his seal** that God is true.

This, God’s seal of the Holy Spirit signifies a complete change of life beginning at conversion which should be conspicuous as a Godly life to those around us.

The idea is used frequently in the book of Revelation (Rev 5 – 9) and also denotes the protection enjoyed by God’s faithful people.

- Rev 7:2, 3 - And I saw another angel ascending from the east, with the seal of the living God. And he called out in a loud voice to the four angels who had been given power to harm the land and the sea: “Do not harm the land or sea or trees until we have sealed the foreheads of the servants of our God.”
- Rev 9:4 - They were told not to harm the grass of the earth or any plant or tree, but only those who did not have the seal of God on their foreheads.

Thus, God’s people are miraculously preserved who have the seal of God which denotes the Name of the Lamb and the Father written on the forehead (Rev 14:2; see also Ex 13:9, 28:38, Eze 9:4).

Answer (score 0):

I think Biblical texts can be interpreted as literal and figurative. For example, “Jesus is the Bread of Life” means Jesus sustains each person as food (bread) sustains humankind. But it is also literal because in the Catholic Church, in the Eucharist celebration, church members eat a wafer which through a mysterious act of God has become the flesh of Jesus (although it still looks and tastes like cracker/bread).

John 6:51

> I am the living bread that came down from heaven. Whoever eats of this bread will live forever; and the bread that I will give for the life of the world is my flesh.

The marking of the forehead with the shape of a cross happens when people become Christians. The person professes their faith and allegiance to Jesus, acknowledges their sin, asks for God’s forgiveness, and has new life in Christ!
Anyone is allowed to be a Christian if they will acknowledge Jesus paid the penalty for their sins!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The seal on our foreheads is a "scar".  Like an open gash or cut, it is "sealed" with stitches.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).